# Set session variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables, laravel-routing, application-variables

I would like to set a variable in the session using laravel this way

```
Session::set('variableName')=$value;
```

but the problem is that I don't know where to put this code, 'cause I would like to set it for one time (when the guest visite the home page or any other page)?
The main idea is to use a global variable to use it in all application controllers, I heared about something related to configuration variables but I'm not sure if it will be a good Idea to use config variables or only the session?
Thanks

Comment: that is illegal PHP. the left-hand-side of an assignment operation cannot be an expression. `set()` is a function/method call - it can only RETURN a value, you cannot assign a value to it.

Comment: This is very well documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The correct syntax for this is:

```
Session::set('variableName', $value);
```

For Laravel 5.4 and later, the correct method to use is `put`:

```
Session::put('variableName', $value);
```

To get the variable, you would use:

```
Session::get('variableName');
```

If you need to set it once, I'd figure out when exactly you want it set and use `Events` to do it.

For example, if you want to set it when someone logs in, you'd use:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function() {
    Session::set('variableName', $value);
});
```

Comment: Please Tell Me Where We Can Use this Event?

Comment: in routes or controller?

Comment: You'd probably want to create a service provider for it and put it in there.

Comment: @user3158900, why there is a need of service provider?

Answer (score 31):

I think your question ultimately can be boiled down to this:

> Where can I set a long-lived value that is accessible globally in my application?

The obvious answer is that it depends.  What it depends on are a couple of factors:

- Will the value ever be different, or is it going to be the same for everybody?
- How long exactly is long-lived? (Forever? A Day? One browsing 'session'?)

**Config**

If the value is the same for everyone and will seldom change, the best place to probably put it is in a configuration file somewhere underneath `app/config`, e.g. `app/config/companyname.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'somevalue' => 10,
];
```

You could access this value from anywhere in your application via `Config::get('companyname.somevalue')`

**Session**

If the value you are intending to store is going to be *different* for each user, the most logical place to put it is in `Session`.  This is what you allude to in your question, but you are using incorrect syntax.  The correct syntax to store a variable in Session is:

```
Session::put('somekey', 'somevalue');
```

The correct syntax to retrieve it back out later is:

```
Session::get('somekey');
```

As far as *when* to perform these operations, that's a little up to you.  I would probably choose a [route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) if on Laravel 4.x or [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) if using Laravel 5.  Below is an example of using a route filter that leverages another class to actually come up with the value:

```
// File: ValueMaker.php (saved in some folder that can be autoloaded)
class ValueMaker
{
    public function makeValue()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

// File: app/filters.php is probably the best place
Route::filter('set_value', function() {
    $valueMaker = app()->make('ValueMaker');
    Session::put('somevalue', $valueMaker->makeValue());
});

// File: app/routes.php
Route::group(['before' => 'set_value'], function() {
   // Value has already been 'made' by this point. 
   return View::make('view')
       ->with('value', Session::get('somevalue'))
   ;
});
```

Comment: upvote because of hhtg :-) and the good and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel 5.6, you will need to set it as:

```
session(['variableName' => $value]);
```

To retrieve it, is as simple as:

```
$variableName = session('variableName');
```

Comment: Can I retrieve it from any controller ?

Comment: yes, A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages

Answer (score 12):

For example, To store data in the session, you will typically use the `put`method or the `session` helper:

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

or

```
// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

for retrieving an item from the session, you can use `get` :

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default value');
```

or global `session` helper :

```
$value = session('key', 'default value');
```

To determine if an item is present in the session, you may use the `has` method:

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
//
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To add to the above answers, ensure you define your function like this:

```
public function functionName(Request $request)  {
       //
}
```

Note the "(Request $request)", now set a session like this:

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

And retrieve the session in this way:

```
$data = $request->session()->get('key');
```

To erase the session try this:

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

or

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

Answer (score 6):

in Laravel 5.4

use this method:

```
Session::put('variableName', $value);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 6.x

```
// Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
$value = session('key');

// Specifying a default value...
$value = session('key', 'default');

// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
 Session::put('variable_Name', "Your Data Save Successfully !");  
 Session::get('variable_Name');
```

Comment: This is used to store value in session \Session::put('variable_Name', "Your Data Save Successfully !"); and this is used Session::get('variable_Name');
to get the value which i store in session

Answer (score 1):

to set session you can try this:

```
$request->session()->put('key','value');
```

also to get session data you can try this:

```
$request->session()->get('key');
```

If you want to get all session data:

```
$request->session()->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want persistence sessions,

Method 1: use `session()->save()` or `Session::save()`

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
//or
session()->put('key', 'value');

//then
session()->save();

echo session('key');
```

Method 2: Move bellow line from `protected $middlewareGroups` of `app\Http\Kernel.php` to `protected $middleware` array as first line

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Make sure the storage directory has write permission

```
chmod -R a+rw storage/
```

Don't use `dd()` to verify session, use `print_r()`