# How to fetch the values one controller to another controller

Tags: laravel, redirect, view, controller

In laravel,I'm using redirect function to redirect to another controller with values,like redirect('my-page,with['value1']=>$values) and im getting the values using session->flash(),I got the values,but if I refresh the page,my values are gone,how to solve it

Tried many methods if the page was refreshed,I got null values

Comment: Flash is flash - this is one time values. You can pass values with query string or store in session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set session variable in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417796/set-session-variable-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

```php
Session::put('value1', $values);
return redirect('my-page');
```

in other controller:

```php
Session::get('value1');
```